# How to convert genre column to numerical value so that I can feed it to the neural network model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding, data-preprocessing

In the image attached below, the genre column has multiple attributes for a single entry. I am trying to build a neural network model and for that I need to encode it. I am having problems regarding that.

Comment: Where is the image.

Comment: Read this post: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-dummy-variables-in-python-with-pandas/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are tree options:

- One Hot Encoding: each label is mapped to a binary vector;
- Integer Encoding: each unique label is mapped to an integer;
- Use Embedding: will map each of the unique category into a N-dimensional vector;

Comment: Yes, I knew that but can you please elaborate on how to apply that on a column. For instance, I have a skills column where there are multiple skills in the form of an array in a single row and the unique skills are more than 100. Should I apply one-hot encoding if I do that the number of columns will increase and I do not know how that will affect the neural network model.